# handle HTTP status codes in Angular 5

Tags: angular5

I'm trying to capture http status codes in angular in service which calls a backend service, i'm facing issues as i see status 204 , but when logging angular show status null, here is what i'm doing in my service:

```
return this.http.get<JSON>(mybackendsserviceurl)
      .do(res => {
      })
      .catch(res => {
        return this.handleError(res);
      });
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return Observable.throw(err.message);
  }
```

How to catch different errors from backend service, like 204,403,404,500...etc and display a user friendly message for each error?
my frontend is calling the service from API gateway and i'm setting the errors in Response Integrations.

Comment: Where do you log the status code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle different status codes just check them:

```
this.http.get<JSON>(<URL>)
    .subscribe( 
        res => console.log(res), 
        err => {
            console.error(err);
            this.handleError(err);
        });


private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if( err.status == 500 ) {

        return Observable.throw(new Error(<YOUR USERFRIENDLY MESSAGE>));

    } else if( err.status == 400 ) {

        return Observable.throw(new Error(<YOUR MESSAGE>));
    }

    // you can also catch all errors of a group like this
    else if( err.status < 500 && err.status >= 400 ) {

        return Observable.throw(new Error(<CLIENT ERROR MESSAGE>));
    }
}
```

In your UI you can handle the `Observable` and of course, show a nice dialog with the error message.

Comment: When adding this in the HandleError, none of console log comes up
`private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if( err.status == 500 ) {
    console.log(err.status,"500 from servce");
        return Observable.throw(new Error(<YOUR USERFRIENDLY MESSAGE>));
    }

    if( err.status == 400 ) {
        return Observable.throw(newError(<YOUR MESSAGE>));
    }
}`

Comment: how do you log errors? Do you produce an HTTP error and is the `.catch` executed?

Comment: in UI i see: Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error
and in network tab i see code 403 however the backend is 404

Comment: console.log(err.message); prints: 
`Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error`
none of the status set above is executed

Comment: You have probably a problem with CORS. Try the same page with Google Chrome and see, what the JS console writes.

Comment: Yes, i'm on chrome and the console has following errors: 
 `OPTIONS 403 () requestURL` then
`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: You can configure your backend and add the necessary headers. Otherwise there are some workarounds: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/http-with-promises/ . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: Thank you :) however the same problem persists not just in localhost, also on dev and different environments, the backend already has CORS configured, when i can the service from load balancer i don't see the problem, only from api gateway URL.  do you have any suggestion?

Comment: installing chrome extension to disable CORS, now i see the console.log as:
`Cannot read property 'status' of null`, while in network the status is 204

Comment: Your answer works, making it as a solution, Thank you :)